# Unable to use 'http' module in Salesforce Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, salesforce, node-modules

I am writing code with [Salesforce Functions](https://github.com/trailheadapps/functions-recipes), in javascript, adding the 'require' statement below

```
export default async function (event, context, logger) {
    var http = require('http'); // runtime error is thrown
```

causes a runtime error of

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error
Function threw: require is not defined
```

when I try to access the function/service.

I looked for any answers from here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/index, and the github recipe link above, no luck.

Comment: Are you running the require on the front-end? If so, that maybe the cause. As browsers don't have the require method defined. It's used in Node.js environment.

You could potentially fix this by installing browserify.

Comment: Hi Rayne, thanks for the response. Salesforce Functions objects run on the server, not on the client or browser side.

Comment: Try placing the require at the top level of server, instead of inside a function call. then use the variable elsewhere. As this way it'll have global scope opposed to function scope.